# Python string ('$' followed by characters rather than numbers)

Tags: python, string-formatting

May I ask if I just want to filter all the string of "$" followed by characters but not those followed by numbers, what python codes should I modify based on the following codes I have? Thanks.

```
def color_negative_red(value):
    if '$' in value:
        color = 'red'
 
    else:
        color = 'black'

    return 'color: %s' % color

Dataframe = Dataframe.style.applymap(color_negative_red, subset=['column_1'])
```

Comment: Might I suggest using a regular expression for the job?

Comment: Sure, any method will be welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use regex and specifically a lookahead assertion:

```
import re

if re.search(r'\$(?=[A-Za-z]+)', value):
    color = 'red'
```

This will find any letter character following a `$` except digits.

Comment: Thank you Jab for your help! This solved my problem completely.